# NZR signal and multiplexer 74LVC1G157

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, signal, ws2812b

I'm trying to use a [WS2812B](https://www.digikey.com/en/datasheets/parallaxinc/parallax-inc-28085-ws2812b-rgb-led-datasheet) addressable LED with a multiplexer [74LVC1G157](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G157.pdf). I have test code on an Arduino, and if I connect the LED to I0 or I1, the color of the LED changes, but the delay selector part doesn't do anything.

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define I0        5
#define I1        6
#define SELECTOR 10
#define NUMPIXELS 1

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixel0(NUMPIXELS, I0, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800); 
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixel1(NUMPIXELS, I1, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);   

void setup() {
  pinMode(SELECTOR,OUTPUT);
  pixel0.begin();
  pixel1.begin();
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(SELECTOR, HIGH);
  pixel0.clear();
  pixel1.clear();
  
  pixel0.setPixelColor(0, pixel0.Color(0, 0, 80)); 
  pixel0.show();
  delay(500);
  pixel0.setPixelColor(0, pixel0.Color(0, 80, 80)); 
  pixel0.show();
  pixel1.setPixelColor(0, pixel1.Color(80, 0, 0));
  pixel1.show();
  
  digitalWrite(SELECTOR, HIGH);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(SELECTOR, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(SELECTOR, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
}
```

I suspect that maybe there is a problem with the support board multiplexer I'm using. Where could the problem be? Is there something wrong on my code?

I have tried to change the selector pin manually, connecting to GND and V+ and it only works when it is connected to V+, to GND does nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino libraries have documentation and documentation says how the library works and how it should be used, so this behaviour is expected based on how your code uses the library.

The multiplexer most likely works fine, there just is no data transmissions going on at the data pins when your code changes the multiplexer. The data is transmitted out only when show() method is called.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem, but I understand why if I change manually de select pin to GND or V+ changes de colour, but if I change the SELECTOR value nothing happens.

Comment: I don't know what your loop does when you change the mux manually, but it must mean the code calls show() for both pixels if your pixels changes color based on mux selector.